# Programmatically create a csproj on the fly without Visual Studio installed

Tags: c#, csproj

I am attempting to generate a .csproj file programatically using the `MSBuild` namespace, but the lack of code samples is making this a tedious and error prone process.

So far, I have got the following code but I am not sure how to add classes, references and such to the project.

```
public void Build()
{
    string projectFile = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}.csproj", Common.GetApplicationDataFolder(), _project.Target.AssemblyName);
    Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project p = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project();

    ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();

    Dictionary<string, string> globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    globalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
    globalProperty.Add("Platform", "x64");

    BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFile, globalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);

    p.Save(projectFile);

    BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(pc), buildRequest);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would love to know the use case of this. You want to generate csproj files for someone else, who has VS, to use?

Comment: Sounds like a strange request.  Have you looked at the Mono source on GitHub?

Comment: This is not a strange request. I want to generate an API dynamically that contains some functionality taken from an XML file that determines what will be included in the API.  I will then call MSBuild to compile the project into an actual assembly.

Comment: woah, interesting. Wish I could help more. It sounds like you just need to make a list of exactly what you need (as you said, `classes, references and such`), and figure them one one-by-one.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. It is possible to dynamically emit assemblies using Reflection.Emit or compile dynamically generated code using CodeDom. I don't see why MSBuild is necessary based on what you've told us.

Comment: You are using the MSBuild api.  It *consumes* project files, it doesn't create them.  You need XmlWriter.Create()

Comment: From what I have done so far MSBuild can create project files so you don't need to use `Reflection.Emit`.

Comment: @MikeClarke - I think what he's saying is that it's a little indirect to generate source, generate project files, then invoke msbuild, then consume the produced assembly. You can use Expression Trees and Reflection.Emit to produce an assembly directly, removing the intermediate steps. Either approach is viable, and which one makes sense for you depends on your goals. The MSBuild path is more steps, but maybe easier since you know how to generate code, and might be helpful to view the intermediate code. Expression Trees might be better because they're more direct.

Comment: @antiduh I wanted to use `MSBuild` to create the project files because I have got several base classes as embedded resources and it's a simple matter of saving these s `.cs` files and then add them dynamically to the `.csproj` file.  At the moment it doesn't look like MSBuild allows creation of new project files so I might have to look at creating the `.csproj` file as described by Hans after all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to create a proj file with MSBuild API you have to use the Microsoft.Build.Construction namespace. Most of the types you will need are in the Micrsoft.Build.dll assembly. A short sample that creates a project file with a few properties and item groups:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = ProjectRootElement.Create();
        var group = root.AddPropertyGroup();
        group.AddProperty("Configuration", "Debug");
        group.AddProperty("Platform", "x64");

        // references
        AddItems(root, "Reference", "System", "System.Core");

        // items to compile
        AddItems(root, "Compile", "test.cs");

        var target = root.AddTarget("Build");
        var task = target.AddTask("Csc");
        task.SetParameter("Sources", "@(Compile)");
        task.SetParameter("OutputAssembly", "test.dll");

        root.Save("test.csproj");
        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("test.csproj"));
    }

    private static void AddItems(ProjectRootElement elem, string groupName, params string[] items)
    {
        var group = elem.AddItemGroup();
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            group.AddItem(groupName, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this just creates the proj file. It doesn't run it. Also, properties like "Configuration" and "Platform" are only meaningful in the context of a proj file generated by Visual Studio. Here they won't really do anything unless you add more property groups with conditions the way Visual Studio does automatically.

Like I indicated in my comments, I think this is wrong way to go about this. You really just want dynamic compilation of sources, which is available through CodeDom:

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
        string[] sources = {
                               @"public abstract class BaseClass { public abstract void Test(); }",
                               @"public class CustomGenerated : BaseClass { public override void Test() { System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World""); } }"
                           };

        var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(new CompilerParameters() {
            GenerateExecutable = false,
            ReferencedAssemblies = { "System.dll", "System.Core.dll" },
            IncludeDebugInformation = true,
            CompilerOptions = "/platform:anycpu"
        }, sources);
        if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} errors", results.Errors.Count);
            foreach(CompilerError error in results.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var type = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("CustomGenerated");
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            type.GetMethod("Test").Invoke(instance, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying to use `MSBuild` I have admitted defeat and decided to bow to greater wisdom and use `CodeDom` instead.  It is possible to do it using `MSBuild` but it's a lot more convoluted and complicated.  It would certainly have helped if Microsft had better documentation.