# How to change C# version in atom-editor?

Tags: c#, atom-editor

I don't use Visual Studio and I wanted to find my .csproj file to change my C# version.

I use atom editor and then compile my files in cmd, I was told to look for it in my project's folder but it's not there

Comment: which version you .net are you using?

Comment: It's better to reach atom-editor support or github

Comment: @viveknuna Does that matter in the .csproj's file location? I use an older version because i wanted to find how to get .csproj before updating windows and .NET to 4.8

Comment: @Octavylon because in VS 2019 there is option to place solution and project in the same directory

Comment: i don't use visual studio @viveknuna

Comment: Which line you use to compile? Normally you would target a csproj file, but since it's not there you must use a different target, or maybe just a whole folder. If so, you just might be able to create the file yourself

Comment: Maybe this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-msbuild-project-file-from-scratch?view=vs-2019 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557807/programmatically-create-a-csproj-on-the-fly-without-visual-studio-installed will help you

Comment: i compiled like this: c:\windows\microsoft.NET\framework\v3.5\csc.exe /t:exe /out:Example.exe Example.cs

Comment: yw, please consider to add your fix as answer for future use :-)